# Window 8.1 app deployment

Tags: deployment, appstore, windows-8

I have the following scenario: client asks to develop an application for his company. It will be a simple frontend, rest api and Oracle database. It needs to be installed on 15 devices which will work in a local network and use some rest api to save/read data from database.

Now the question is: can I deploy this app to store? Because it will work for only my client of course. Or should I go with sideloading approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting an app on a public store shows that app to the public. This gives you a whole load of marketing problems about how it should be displayed, what licence should be used etc.

Also even if the app is non functional for other users it may reveal some comerically significant information through the UI design for example.

I would go with a side loading approach to avoid these issues.

If the client has many apps I believe MS has a 'apps for my company only' solution.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/business-store/